# Weird async problem with Firebase databse

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

So I'm new with async and I'm having a weird problem here. I'm been reading a lot about it and can't seem to make it work. When I'm trying to put Firebase data into an array of object, it shows up as an empty array, but if I click on it I can see what is inside with a message saying : "Value was evaluated just now". My code is all inside the .then() and if I use JSON.stringify on it, I can see the JSON version of the object, but if I use JSON.parse on the stringified object, it goes back to the empty object.

Here is my code :

```
let premiereEtoile = [];
let deuxiemeEtoile = [];
let troisiemeEtoile = [];

let resultats = [];

function joueurExiste(nom) {
return resultats.some(function(el) {
    return el.nom === nom
});
};

db.collection('premiereEtoile').get().then((snapshot) => {
snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    premiereEtoile.push(doc.data().premiere);

});
premiereEtoile.forEach(nom => {
    if (joueurExiste(nom)) {
        let i = resultats.findIndex(x => x.nom == nom);
        resultats[i].points += 3

    }
    else {
        resultats.push({ nom: nom, points: 3})
    };
});



});


db.collection('deuxiemeEtoile').get().then((snapshot) => {
snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    deuxiemeEtoile.push(doc.data().deuxieme);

});
deuxiemeEtoile.forEach(nom => {
    if (joueurExiste(nom)) {
        let i = resultats.findIndex(x => x.nom == nom);
        resultats[i].points += 2

    }
    else {
        resultats.push({ nom: nom, points: 2})
    };
});
});

db.collection('troisiemeEtoile').get().then((snapshot) => {
snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    troisiemeEtoile.push(doc.data().troisieme);

});
troisiemeEtoile.forEach(nom => {
    if (joueurExiste(nom)) {
        let i = resultats.findIndex(x => x.nom == nom);
        resultats[i].points += 1

    }
    else {
        resultats.push({ nom: nom, points: 1})
    };
});
let resultatsJSON = (JSON.stringify(resultats));
console.log(resultatsJSON);
console.log(JSON.parse(resultatsJSON));

});
```

The console logs :

```
[{"nom":"elodie turcotte","points":3},{"nom":"leonie-alain","points":6},{"nom":"alexandre-sacha-simoneau","points":9},{"nom":"sabrina-pariseau","points":6},{"nom":"felix-boudreault","points":3},{"nom":"simon-turcotte","points":4},{"nom":"felix-auger","points":2},{"nom":"alex-martin","points":4},{"nom":"mathieu-grondin","points":2},{"nom":"mathieu-muir","points":1},{"nom":"sandrine-voyer","points":1}]
(11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Thank you !

Comment: first, do you understand that the three `db.collection('....').get().then((snapshot) => {` are essentially running in parallel - so, there's no way for you to know which of the loops will update `resultats` first and which will run last

Comment: Is there a way to make them run one at a time ? Also if I try to parse the JSON only in the first db.collection, I still get the same result for the first part of the 3 db.collection, I can't read the object.

Comment: to run one at a time ... chain the promises ... like https://pastebin.com/MAWEdfQ4 ... to run in parallel correctly, something like https://pastebin.com/qUymjDrV

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense ! I still get the exact same result for the Object, or the parsed JSON of the object.

Comment: Right, I must not understand what the problem is - you do understand how to use the console and that `[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]` isn't empty